# WP8.1 BackgroundMediaPlayer not playing on device, but works on emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, background-audio

I have a universal Windows store project. In `Windows Phone` part, I use a `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` to play audio. The app getting access to media files through `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`.
The problem is when I run my app on emulator with virtual SD Card, music plays and all goes nice. But when I deploy the app to my `Lumia 920` running `WP8.1 DevPreview`, and press 'Play' button, then nothing happens. No exceptions, no force-close... Completely nothing.
Question: Is this an internal storage issue (`Lumia 920` have no SD Card) or `BackgroundMediaPlayer` have a bug or bug is hiding in OS preview version?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

If you register to the handler: `mediaPlayer.MediaFailed += mediaPlayer_MediaFailed;` you will find out that you get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when playing local songs (not on SD card).

Here is what i did and how i solved it:

The error occurs due to `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource`, which for whatever reason only works for files on SD cards.

So instead of passing the path of the file to `SetUriSource`, I loaded the `StorageFile` with

```
StorageFile sf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(musicDataFullPath);
```

and then

```
mediaPlayer.SetStreamSource((await sf.OpenStreamForReadAsync()).AsRandomAccessStream());
```

and so now it works....